# Cloud Datastore best practise: storing data that needs to be accessed from multiple regions

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I currently have multiple identical GAE web applications (one hosted in EU, one hosted in US, and plans to add other regions), each storing information in Cloud Datastore (in the region of the GAE app).

I am looking to introduce a domain based subscription that needs to cater for users in any region (i.e user 1 of domain 1 is in the US and user 2 of domain 1 is in EU).

**What is the best method of storing information that needs to be accessed from multiple regions?**

Current thoughts are:

1. storing all subscription information in 1 region.
2. creating a look up table in 1 region that directs the app to the relevant region for the subscription information.

I am hesitant in storing all subscription information in 1 region as it somewhat defeats the purpose of having two regions (i.e some personal information could be stored in two regions).

Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Don't understand why you would like to keep them as separate instances? Best practice is to have data in one place, and you scale it through different regions/availability zones. If I understand correctly now, if user registers in region1, he can also register with the same name in region2? If you need that separation, then I would myself go with your option number 1. especially if the subscription needs to be handled by single billing department etc. this is an easier way to process the data.

Comment: @MaksimLuzik Two GAE instances (and datastores) are running for data sovereignty reasons. To clarify the situation...an individual can only ever register in one region. However, individuals within the same domain may be in different regions (e.g john@example.com is in the US while peter@example.com is in EU). I would like to allow the organisation to subscribe to a domain subscription, however I am unsure the best way to recognise the individuals are in a domain subscription since the datastores are separate.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can use [Remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/remoteapi) to access cross-project Datastores, you can do whatever you want. What's best would depend on what you value more. You can duplicate all the information into both Datastores to be "safe" OR you can simply store them in one Datastore for ease of management OR you can store particular user information based on where the user registered onto the closest Datastore.

You have to consider how often the "cross-project" datastore calls would occur in order to optimize your storage. For example, if user's registration and password is stored in project A but his user data is in project B, then virtually every user would need to make a remote api call when using your apps. I would store the data logically based on how they might be accessed in a single session with an user.

Also, if you are worried about data redundancy, a single region is not a single point of failure; there are multiple zones in a region where the data exists. So even if all your data is in one project in one region, it still has redundancy.